# How to automatically connect to Cloud SQL via the proxy?

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-app-engine, proxy

I have mySQL database set in settings.py like this:

```
if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):
    # Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
    # the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/myApp:europe-west1:myApp-instance',
            'NAME': 'myApp',
            'USER': 'myApp',
            'PASSWORD': 'myApp', }}
else:
    # Running locally so connect to either a local MySQL instance or connect to
    # Cloud SQL via the proxy. To start the proxy via command line:
    #
    #     $ ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances="myApp:europe-west1:myApp-instance"=tcp:3306
    #
    # See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-connect-proxy
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '3306',
            'NAME': 'myApp',
            'USER': 'myApp',
            'PASSWORD': 'myApp', }}
```

When I want to run myApp locally I must run first on terminal this command:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances="myApp:europe-west1:myApp-instance"=tcp:3306
```

and it's very annoying... there is a way to integrate it inside my code?

For example I would put something in my setting that automatically run the command, immediately after the 'else:'
But I don't know what I have to write... any idea? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `os.system` to run a shell command from Python code:

```
os.system('./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=\"myApp:europe-west1:myApp-instance\"=tcp:3306')
```

or `subprocess`:

```
subprocess.call(['./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=\"myApp:europe-west1:myApp-instance\"=tcp:3306'], shell=True)
```